# PhpStorm can`t upload file to FTP server with VCS system on my project

Tags: svn, ftp, phpstorm

I have setup my PhpStorm project tn upload edited files to FTP server on **Ctrl + S**

[image: config ftp]

But it doesn't work when I include VCS **subversion**

[image: synch changes]

What should I do to upload changed file on FTP server?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure here .. but so far it look like your file on the left (from 2nd screenshot) is located outside of the project...

Comment: I suppose, i should make commit, and when all changed files will be upload.  But i want do it without commit.

Comment: I do not know how Subversion works. For me (based on screenshots) file is outside of the project .. which means -- IDE does not know how to map it properly to the remote path (as I see it from over here). No other ideas. If anything -- try PhpStorm support directly -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: @LazyOne You were right. I excluded some file from download then i create FTP and forgot about it. Now i remove excluded paths from **Deployment > Configuratin** and it's works. Many thanks for your response.